# firebase subquery and also head query in next js as getinitialprops

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to have the query with subquery. Lets see the first query:

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    let product = []
    const PostId = ctx.query.pid;
    await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('products')
    .doc(PostId)
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        return product
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
    

return {product: product[0]}
}
```

now I got the information from that query, but I also need subcollections. I found out how to get all subcollection like this, but then I lose the data from above query.

```
static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    let product = []
    const PostId = ctx.query.pid;
    await firebase.firestore()
    .collection('products')
    .doc(PostId)
    .collection('offers')
    .orderBy('position', 'asc')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
        return product
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error', error)
    })
    

return {product: product[0]}
}
```

So is it possible to combine this toghether and get all from collection('products').doc(postID) and all from collection('products').doc(postID).collection('offers') ? So all in one query.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible in one query.  Firestore queries are shallow and only consider documents immediately within the collection being queried.  There are no SQL-like joins between collections.  If you need documents from multiple collections, you will have to perform multiple queries.

The only type of query that can get documents from multiple collections is a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), and those only consider documents among all collections with the same name.  You could use that to query all documents among all "offers" subcollections, but you wouldn't be able to filter by anything in a parent document.